# Development process with multiple solutions in nuget

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I want to create a repository which will consist of multiple solutions and each solution will be publish to local nuget server.

But i don't understand how to make a development process when i want to edit solution A and test it with another solution B which references to solution A through nuget package without publishing solution A on nuget server after each build? If i make project reference in solution B it will bring the right dependency and i don't want it.

To be clearly, for example: i want to add some functionality in solution B and to do it i need to change solution A. Solution B has nuget-reference to solution A. If i change solution A i have to publish it to nuget server and than wait till nuget server updates and only than can test it with solution B, it looks pretty bad for me.

And answer for question why i need it:
We're building microservices and decided to develop each microservice in separate solution and each shared library in theirs standalone solutions too. And all of this in one repository :-)

Comment: Remove the nuget package and add a direct reference to the project.

Comment: @SamAxe as i wrote this way seems bad for me, f.e, my college or i can forget to remove direct reference

Comment: I agree with Sam. We are doing the same at our company and debugging the nuget packages isn't possible. Take a look at the Nuget Package Switcher which we're also thinking of using to alleviate such issues. It changes refs from nuget refs to project refs: https://github.com/rsuter/NuGetReferenceSwitcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Development process with multiple solutions in nuget

NuGet has many advantages as a package manager for the Microsoft development platform, but that does not mean it is not flawed. Just as you encountered, if the referenced project is modified frequently, we have to rebuild it, create nuget package, publish it to nuget server and wait till nuget server updates for each modification. That will bring a lot of boring work. To resolve this disadvantages, the Project-to-project references should be a better way. So Sam and Ieemac`s suggestion should be recommended.

The advantage of a project-to-project reference is that it creates a dependency between the projects in the build system. The dependent project will be built if it has changed since the last time the referencing project was built. A file reference does not create a build dependency, so it is possible to build the referencing project without building the dependent project.

So **the best solutions** is that the project-to-project reference should be recommend when the referenced project is modified frequently, the nuget reference is more appropriate when share the reference project to others or publish it. Just like [NuGet Reference Switcher](https://github.com/rsuter/NuGetReferenceSwitcher) doing.

Comment: But we are using the docker, so there is problem that i need to copy all external project directories in Dockerfile in order to compile some service. With nuget that projects will be included automatically. So that is way we want to use nuget packages instead of direct references.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation. You have to use nuget packages insteadof direct references, in this case, rebuild, create nuget package, publish it to server are not be unavoidable. That is because nuget manage assemblies by packing it as a whole. Any modification need to repack and publish.